# Precalculus: what is the $x$ value of a parabola $y^2=4px$ when $y = 0,$ if the vertex is given at $(0,4)$ and the point $(10,3)$ exists

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

> Water squirting out of a horizontal nozzle held $4$ ft above
> the ground describes a parabolic curve with the vertex at
> the nozzle. If the stream of water drops $1$ ft in the first
> $10$ ft of horizontal motion, at what horizontal distance
> from the nozzle will it strike the ground?

So far I have visualized that this parabola is probably a $y^2=4px$ or $y^2 = x$, the focus must be some $(a,4)$ and its directrix some $(-a,4)$, with the vertex of this parabola at $y=4.$ The $y$ axis should be describing the height and the $x$ axis horizontal distance.

For it to hit the ground I should be finding some $x$ value when $y^2 = 0.$ However just by simply substituting it to be $0$ causes the equation to have no $x$ value.

I have kinda found out the $p$ value of this parabola by doing $\sqrt{10^2+(3-p)^2} = (3+p)^2$ where $p = 25/3.$ (I used $3$ as the question says it drops by $1$ ft), but it doesn't seem to help as described above.

I wonder if I should be trying something else but I am stuck.

Comment: A general parabola would have equation $y=a(x-c)^2+d$ where the vertex is at (c,d). In your case the vertex is at (0,4). So you have $y=ax^2+4$. Can you take it from here? Solve for a, then find the x when y=0.

Comment: Hi Ameet, I have tried your suggestion and I got x = 20. graphically it makes sense so I think this should be the answer, thanks.

I didn't know that there was a equation for a general parabola in my textbook, lol

Comment: That's what I got also. Cool. :)

Comment: for some reason the graph $y\ =\ -\frac{1}{100}x^{2}+4$ is like the following: https://i.gyazo.com/3fe65ca77e2a285dbcd4c329396cd15e.png which is not what i expected, especially when they say that the nozzle is held horizontally with the vertex at the nozzle. shouldn't the vertex be described as a line y = a?

Comment: That looks right. The right half of the graph but above the y axis applies to your problem. The water hits the ground at y=0.

Comment: The vertex is a point at (0,4). Think of the nozzle held horizontally at that vertex. Water flows to the right and falls down to the ground. Have a look at the picture here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law. Water flows out to the right and falls down.

Comment: Alright thanks Ameet for that visualization, understood. I had previously thought that a vertex wasn't a coordinate but it was a line, lol.

May I also know how does completing the square in $y = ax2 + bx + c$ to $y = (x − h)2 + d$ allow us to use the vertex $(h,d)$ as $h$ and $d$ in the second equation?

What was the previous identity of the constants $a$,$b$ and $c$? Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115051/discussion-between-ameet-sharma-and-neried).